# How to use multiple sets in class property when dealing with methods with multiple parameters?

Tags: c#, oop, class

I have a class that contains the following method (The Class name is ZipLoad):

```
    private string DOit(string uName, string pWord)
    {
      DOSTUFF.....
      return "Successfull";  
    }
```

Now I want pass parameters to the class using my program but there are two parameters. If there was one parameter i would simply do this:

```
    private string testUser;
    public string getSetUser
    {
        get { return testUser; }
        set { testUser= DOit(value); }
    }
```

And then use my Windows Forms Application to pass the parameters.

```
     ZipLoad myZipLoad = new ZipLoad();

     string report;
     myZipLoad.testUser = "userName";
     report= myZipLoad.getSetUser;
```

My Question is that how do I pass parameters to the DOit method using public properties in the class. One way is to make the method public but for some reason people say that is bad.

Any help would be appreciated ...
Thank You

Comment: Methods are interfaces to outside world.You dont benefit much by making it private.The state(member fields) of your class should be private and not your methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe i'm wrong but `set { testUser= DOit(value); }` doesn't looks very useful what you are trying because if you get this to work and you are doing

```
myZipLoad.testUser = "userName";
report= myZipLoad.getSetUser;
string user = myZipLoad.testUser; //<- user == "Successfull"
```

so i build you this construct

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ZipLoad myZipLoad = new ZipLoad();

            string report;
            myZipLoad.TestUser = "userName";
            report = myZipLoad.Stat; //<- modified
        }
    }


    class ZipLoad
    {
        #region private Values

        private string testUser;
        private string pWord;

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public string TestUser
        {
            get { return testUser; }
            set { testUser = value; }
        }

        public string PWord
        {
            private get { return pWord; }
            set { pWord = value; }
        }

// ADDED
        public string Stat
        {
            get { return DOit_aka_Login(testUser, pWord); }
        }

        #endregion

        private string DOit_aka_Login(string uName, string pWord) //<- modified
        {
            // now you may need to check the input  if(uName =="" && pWord==""){...}
            //DOSTUFF.....
            return "Successfull";
        }
    }
```

if it doesn't fit your needs please add more information's

Comment: Isn't there any way by which I don't have to make the "DOit_aka_Login()" method public ???
I mean why use properties then ??? 
Why don't we directly pass the parameters to the Doit_aka_Login() method ???

Comment: Yep that did it...   
So now I don't need to have get{} with the other two properties.. right ???

Comment: @WaqasAli **right**, but you also can set it as private getter `private get { return ...; }`

Comment: Also , what if the method does not return anything i.e void... What do I do then to get the job done ?

Comment: @WaqasAli  if you test it you will see you can do `myZipLoad.testUser = "userName"`but you can't do `string myString = myZipLoad.testUser;` because the getter is `private` you can also set him as `protected`

Comment: @WaqasAli Sorry - I don't quite follow. what do you mean?

Comment: I mean what if the DOit_aka_Login() method is void... i.e ""  private **void** DOit_aka_Login(string uName, string pWord)  "". What do I do now ???